# C++ static_assert to check whether a template had been instantiated with a specific type

Tags: c++, templates, static-assert

Motivation: I'm trying to warn future maintainers that if they do something in the code they must make sure to do something else too

**Please note that "instantiation" here means template instantiation and not *object of class* instantiation.**

```
class A;
class B;

template<class T> void foo() {}
template<class T> class X {};

void f()
{
    foo<A>();   
}

void g()
{
    X<A> x; // ok
    X<B> y; // expecting static_assert here: if instantiated X with a type, 
            // foo must be instantiated with the same type too
}
```

Comment: Did you already try something yourself? [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) are some useful standard facilities.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing template specialization but it fails for two reasons:

Comment: I'm afraid you can't couple two unrelated templates using some static assertion. Can't you integrate `foo()` into the template class? E.g. as `static` member function?

Comment: Yes, I tried doing template specialization but it fails for two reasons:
(1) if I try to reference the name of the template instance (like foo<B>), that is already instantiation.
(2) I should specialize something generally false to true inside the template definition, but it is in another scope

`template <class T> struct is_instantiated : std::false_type {};`
`template<class T> void foo() {`
`template <> struct is_instantiated : std::true_type {};`
`}`

Comment: It is not important for me that they be 1 class - 1 function template. It would be nice in any combination... yes I can wrap the function in a class if that helps, but I couldn't find a solution that way neither

Comment: Are you wanting a `foo<T>();` call, for each T, inside of `f()`? As in, `f` could be named `foo_all_the_Xs`?

Answer (score 0):

As for your comment:

> It would be nice in any combination... yes I can wrap the function in a class if that helps, but I couldn't find a solution that way neither

I can't really see what should be left *to solve* with that.

If you have the function in a template class like

```
template<typename T>
class X {
    static void foo() {
        // Do something involving T
    }
};
```

it is already guaranteed that `X<A>` and `X<A>::foo()` are instantiated for the same type.

Comment: Not guaranteed; specialise X and omit foo from the specialisation.